# Display URL address in Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

Creating a simple webbrowser in WinForms application. In my application I have following components:

- A TextBox
- A WebBrowser

Requirement specification:

- When clicking one of the weblinks from the WebBrowser, the URL address should be displayed in the textbox

Goal:

- Display the URL address in the address field.

Problem:

- Don't know which event I should use? I have tried using event `DocumentCompleted` and `VisibleChanged` in component webbrowser, but It didn't work.
- How should I display the URL adress from component WebBrowser to textbox?

Comment: See [dotBrowser project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotbrowser/develop) as example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
this.Browser.DocumentTitleChanged += Browser_DocumentTitleChanged;
private void Browser_DocumentTitleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri url = ((WebBrowser)sender).Document.Url;
    txtUrl.Text = url.ToString();
}
```

or

```
this.Browser.Navigating += Browser_Navigating;
private void Browser_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    Uri url = e.Url;
    txtUrl.Text = url.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What if the document doesn't contain a title, or the title of the previous document and new document are the same?

Comment: @Nate: Do you mean that `DocumentTitleChanged` will not occur in this case? I'm sure, it will.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`Navigated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) event. When the event occurs you can set your textbox's `Text` property to the value of the `WebBrowser`'s [`Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.url.aspx) property, like this:

```
addressBarTextBox.Text = webBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: I think that `Navigating` event is better because in this case address textbox will not "hang" until navigation occurs

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [WebBrowser.Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) event.  It's triggered as soon as the document begins to load.

Example:

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = webBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I was thinking of webBrowser.Url.